# How can I make my Calendar work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with the calendar I designed and coded for a website. For example, the code is stuck on June 15th, 2022 but won't change to the next day and other days afterward. I've tried to remove the set date of the 15th but the whole labeling disappears in the live server I am using javascript to complete this. I provided my code below I hope you guys can help thank you

```js
/*calendar*/
const date = new Date();

const renderCalendar = () => {
  date.setDate(15);

  console.log(date.getDay());

  const monthDays     = document.querySelector(".days");
  const lastDay       = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
  const prevlastDay   = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
  const firstDayIndex = date.getDay();
  const lastDayIndex  = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDay();

  const nextDays = 7 - lastDayIndex - 1;
  const months = 
    [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'
    , 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ];

  document.querySelector(".date h1").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()];
  document.querySelector(".date p").innerHTML  = date.toDateString();

  let days = "";

  for (let x = firstDayIndex; x > 0; x--) {
    date += `<div class="prev-date">${prevlastDay - x + 1}</div>`;
  }

  for (let i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++) {
    if (i === new Date().getDate() && date.getMonth() === new Date().getMonth()) {
      days += `<div class="today">${i}</div>`;
    } else {
      days += `<div>${i}</div>`;
    }
  }

  for (let j = 1; j <= nextDays; j++) {
    days += `<div class="next-date>${j}</div>`;
  }
  monthDays.innerHTML = days;

}



document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
  renderCalendar()
});

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener("click", () => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  renderCalendar()
});

renderCalendar()
```

```css
/* added for better reading */

.calendar__content > div > div {
  display    : inline-Block;
  width      : 3em;
  text-align : center;
  }
```

```html
<!--Calendar-->
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="calendar__container">
    <div id="social" class="calendar__content">
      <div class="months">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left prev"></i>
        <div class="date">
          <h1>June</h1>
          <p>Wednesday June 15, 2022</p>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-angle-right next"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="weekdays">
        <div>Sun</div>
        <div>Mon</div>
        <div>Tue</div>
        <div>Wed</div>
        <div>Thu</div>
        <div>Fri</div>
        <div>Sat</div>
      </div>
      <div class="days">
        <div class="prev-date">29</div>
        <div class="prev-date">30</div>
        <div class="prev-date">31</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>13</div>
        <div>14</div>
        <div class="today">15</div>
        <div>16</div>
        <div>17</div>
        <div>18</div>
        <div>19</div>
        <div>20</div>
        <div>21</div>
        <div>22</div>
        <div>23</div>
        <div>24</div>
        <div>25</div>
        <div>26</div>
        <div>27</div>
        <div>28</div>
        <div>29</div>
        <div>30</div>
        <div class="next-date">1</div>
        <div class="next-date">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bars">
      <h2 class="event-month">June Event Schedule</h2>
      <hr style="color: white;">
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML so we can help you better.

Comment: what say's your debugging ?

Comment: I tried to run your code and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`

Comment: You use the wrong variable so it throws an error and stops working. Look at your first for loop. Use your developer tools.

Comment: `date +=` should probably be `days +=`.

Comment: @connexo what you said worked. Now the only problem now is I can't get the header to change to the exact date. So it shows the 20th which is today but the header still says June 15th, 2022.

Comment: Well, that's what you get from `date.setDate(15);`. **Add your HTML.**

Comment: **Add your HTML**

Comment: html is attached above @connexo

Comment: @MisterJojo html is attached above

Comment: you have js Error => `invalid assignment to const 'date'`

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but I don't think anyone will delve into your code... if it can help you I offer you here something very similar which should I hope at least inspire you

```js
const
  LANG = 'en-US' // 'en-US'  'fr-FR' 
, datPickPrev = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th:nth-of-type(1)')
, datPickNext = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th:nth-of-type(3)')
, datPick_M_Y = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead tr:nth-of-type(1) th:nth-of-type(2)')
, datPickDays = document.querySelector('#date-picker > tbody')
, showMonthYear = dte => dte.toLocaleDateString(LANG, {month:'long', year:'numeric'}).replace(' de ',' ')
  ;
const now       = new Date()
var curr_Y_M_d1 = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),1 ) 

// init Head Days ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let
  newRow = document.querySelector('#date-picker > thead').insertRow()
, wDat   = new Date(curr_Y_M_d1.getTime())
  ;
wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() - wDat.getDay()) 

for (let c=0;c<7;++c)  // set day list [Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat] 
  {
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = wDat.toLocaleDateString(LANG, {weekday:'short'}) // narrow
  wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() +1)
  }

for (let r=0;r<6;++r)     // add day rows  
  datPickDays.appendChild( newRow.cloneNode(true) )

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
setGridDays() 

datPickPrev.onclick =_=>  // previous month
  {
  datPickPrev.classList.add('clickedMonth')
  setGridDays(-1) 
  setTimeout(_=>{ datPickPrev.classList.remove('clickedMonth') }, 200) // click anim
  }
datPickNext.onclick =_=> // next Month
  {
  datPickNext.classList.add('clickedMonth')
  setGridDays(+1) 
  setTimeout(_=>{ datPickNext.classList.remove('clickedMonth')}, 200) // click anim
  }
datPickDays.onclick = ({target : td_el}) => // previous  or next month clicked on calanda day.
  {
  if (!td_el.matches('td')) return
  if (!td_el.matches('td.clickMonth')) 
    {
    let pickedDate = new Date(curr_Y_M_d1.getFullYear(), curr_Y_M_d1.getMonth(), +td_el.textContent ) 
    console.clear()
    console.log( 'pickedDate -->', pickedDate.toDateString(), '<--')
    setTimeout(console.clear, 1500)
    return
    }
  // else no return and do a mov month...

  td_el.classList.add('clickedMonth' )                           // pseudo anin start
  if (parseInt(td_el.textContent) < 20)  datPickNext.click()     // do next month click
  else                                   datPickPrev.click()     // do previous month click
  setTimeout(_=>{ td_el.classList.remove('clickedMonth') }, 200) // pseudo anin end
  }

function setGridDays(movMonth = 0)
  {
  curr_Y_M_d1.setMonth( curr_Y_M_d1.getMonth() + movMonth ) // changing month +-
  let
    cMonth = curr_Y_M_d1.getMonth()
  , wDat   = new Date(curr_Y_M_d1.getTime())
    ;
  wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() - wDat.getDay()) // set on 1st weekDay (sunday)

  datPick_M_Y.textContent =  showMonthYear(curr_Y_M_d1)

  for (let r=0;r<6;++r)
  for (let c=0;c<7;++c)
    {
    datPickDays.rows[r].cells[c].textContent = wDat.getDate()  // day number on month
    datPickDays.rows[r].cells[c].classList.toggle('clickMonth', (wDat.getMonth()!==cMonth))
    datPickDays.rows[r].cells[c].classList.toggle('today', (wDat.toDateString()===now.toDateString()))
    wDat.setDate(wDat.getDate() +1)
    }
  }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  font-family     : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size       : 16px;
  cursor          : pointer;
  }
td,th {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  text-align : center;
  }
thead { 
  background : #0d3269a9;
  color      : #e4eefc;
  text-align : center;
  }
.clickMonth {
  cursor     : pointer;
  }
tbody td.clickMonth {
  background : #b0c4dea8;
  color      : grey;
  }
.clickMonth:hover {
  color      : #c72734;
  background : #dcd91491; 
  }
.clickedMonth  {
  color      : yellow !important;
  background : crimson !important; 
  }
table#date-picker > thead > tr > th:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  }
.today {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #a6deff 60%, whitesmoke 10%, whitesmoke);
  }
tbody td:not(.clickMonth):hover {
  color      : darkblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<table id="date-picker">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="clickMonth">⇦</th> 
      <th colspan="5"> month - year </th> 
      <th class="clickMonth">⇨</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```